# awk split more columns and print first word

Tags: loops, awk, sed, split, cut

I have comma separated file, I would like to split column 15 to $NF (15th  column to last column) with same split condition `split($column,a,"-")` and print for every splited column  `a[1]`. I cannot do loop over column from nth to last and print for every of them.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS="\t" '{for(i;$15<i<$NF,i+1);split($i,a,"_"); print ???}' file.csv
```

example of file printed form 15th column:

```
NBPF1-chr1-16579269-16579502-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16580779-16580863-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16581333-16581592-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16582457-16582758-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16583499-16583796-MedEx
```

What I expect:

```
NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are close: `{for(i=15;i<=$NF;++i){split($i,a,"-"); print a[1]}}`

Comment: `$NF` is the last field content, `NF` is the number, careful with the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/-[^,]*/,"")}1' file
NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1

$ sed 's/-[^,]*//g' file
NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1
```

If that's not really all you need then please edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Change `i=15` or whatever field from where you want to start loop till last field of current line in following `awk` code.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  value=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    split($i, a, /-/)
    value=(value?value OFS:"")a[1]
  }
  print value
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
split($i, a, /-/); printf "%s%s", a[1], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}}' file

NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1
```

Change `i=1` to `i=15` or whatever field position you want to start extracting `-` delimited values from.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d, -f15- file | sed 's/-[^,]*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just replace?
If you only want the first part after split, then no need to split and save to a temp variable:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=15;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s" OFS, gensub(/-.*/,"",1,$i);print ""}' file.csv
```

If will create an empty column at the rightmost place, if you don't want that, then use this:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=15;i<NF;i++)printf "%s" OFS, gensub(/-.*/,"","g",$i);print gensub(/-.*/,"","g",$NF)}' file.csv
```

replace `"\t"` to `,` if you want the output to be comma separated.
It works for GNU awk, needs `gensub` implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Another example, to purely use regex replace:

```
awk '{gsub(/^([^,]*,){14}/,"")}gsub(/-[^,]*(,|$)/,"\t")' file.csv
```

This one just deleted first 14 columns from $0, then delete `-`and things after it in each remaining column.
Tested with gnu awk.

example input:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,NBPF1-chr1-16579269-16579502-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16580779-16580863-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16581333-16581592-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16582457-16582758-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16583499-16583796-MedEx
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,NBPF1-chr1-16579269-16579502-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16580779-16580863-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16581333-16581592-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16582457-16582758-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16583499-16583796-MedEx
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,NBPF0-chr1-16579269-16579502-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16580779-16580863-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16581333-16581592-MedEx,NBPF1-chr1-16582457-16582758-MedEx,NBPF9-chr1-16583499-16583796-MedEx
```

output:

```
NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1
NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1
NBPF0   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF1   NBPF9
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output also show a trailing tab character on each line?

Comment: Good point, just for code conciseness I didn't deal with that here :)   @rowboat

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can get it:

```
awk -v RS='[-,]' 'NR%5==1' file       
NBPF1                                   
NBPF1
NBPF1
NBPF1
NBPF1
```

Or exactly what you expect:

```
awk -v RS='[-,]' 'NR%5==1{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=","} END{print ""}' file
NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1,NBPF1
```